# maven pom to gradle - assembly plugin failure

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm currently having my JAVA Maven projects and trying to migrate it to Gradle. I issued the below command to convert it,

```
gradle init
```

Kindly find the pom.xml, the descriptor xml file of my project and the generated build.gradle files below,

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ProjectA</name>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpos</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpos</artifactId>
        <version>113</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/non-distributable-lib/jpos113.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.test.jpos.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assemble_POSMClient_JPOS_Bridge.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjectRoot</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

build.gradle :

```
description = 'ProjectA'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/non-distributable-lib/jpos113.jar')
}
```

assemble_POSMClient_JPOS_Bridge.xml :

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>assemble_pos</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/../POSMClient-Common/src/main/lib/Packaged-Web-Components</directory>
        <outputDirectory>Packaged-Web-Components</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>www.zip</exclude>
            <exclude>*.uncompressed.js</exclude>
            <exclude>js/lib/cometd/*</exclude>
            <exclude>.gitmodules</exclude>
            <exclude>README.md</exclude>
            <exclude>package.sh</exclude>
            <exclude>updateDojo.sh</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/../POSMClient-Common/src/main/native</directory>
        <outputDirectory>Packaged-Web-Components/</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Note:
When i do a clean there are no exceptions coming up and is successfull, but its failing to generate the assembly jar file.

```
gradle clean
```

Its failing to generate the assembly plugin section in the build.gradle file. Kindly let me know if there is something i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no like-like way of working with maven and gradle. Just running gradle init will not help to resolve most of the pom structure.

Gradle has similar plugin for distribution.

Below link has more details, on how u can write blocks of codes in build.gradle file to achieve assembly and distribution.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html